# Valid iterator range from char on stack

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char c = 'c';
    std::vector<char> v(&c, &c + 1);

    std::cout << v.size() << '\n'; // 1

    return 0;

}
```

Compiler says this program is OK. Does this mean that the pair `&c, &c + 1` are a valid iterator range? Is there not an edge case where `&c + 1` wraps? (I cannot really imagine it being possible that &c + 1 would wrap but it is troubling me what it means!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoth the Standard (emphasis mine),

> **For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.** When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
>   of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is
>   large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of
>      the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression. In other words, if
>     the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P))
>    and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i − n-th elements of the array
>     object, provided they exist. **Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object,
>    the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object**, and if the expression Q points
>   one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
>   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
>    undefined.

(ISO/IEC 14882:2011 §5.7 Additive operators [expr.add] paragraphs 4-5)

So yes, this is perfectly kosher, just like it would be if you were using an array with one element. The *meaning* of `&c + 1` is just like it says: "one past the last element". It doesn't point to any object you're allowed to access, but it's valid to use otherwise.

Comment: In the last sentence of the quote it says, "the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise UB". Does this refer to the hypothetical situation where `&c + 1` overflows or is it referring to something else? (I need to work on my standardese; am not fluent)

Comment: if (both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object) { the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; } else { the behavior is undefined. }

Answer (score 1):

Technically, every pointer is a random access iterator and every random access iterator is an input iterator which is what you need to construct a `std::vector` from a range.

So this is perfectly legal.

Since you can compare input iterators, wrapping would not be a problem because you can just implement the constructor like

```
for (auto i = InputFirst; i != InputLast; ++i)
    //construct the vector
```

If `&c+1` wraps, so does `++i` and then `i==&c+1`, so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The end iterator of a vector does not point to anything. As long as you don't dereference it, it should be fine. It is why the range is considered to be `[first, last)`. This is why when you do this:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v(&a[0], &a[0] + 5);
```

You put `5` and not `4`.

If the vector is empty, then `vector.end() == vector.end()`, and you shouldn't dereference `vector.begin()`.